# Is that possible to get data content length when WebView loading URL

Tags: android, webview

It's very convenient to display web site with WebView in Android.
But i cannot find any method to get the whole url (including images,css) content
length.is it possible to realized ?

Answer (score 0):

```
                        String url1 = "";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            }
            URL url = new URL(revisedUrl);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();                
            connection.connect();               
            String result = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream());              
        int lengthofdownfile=result.length();//content length also same like this
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.print("filelength"+lengthofdownfile);
```

File sDownlodafile = new File(mTranscription.getfilename().getAbsoluteFile(),  + dateFormat.format(date) + ".wav");

```
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                        url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                        sDownlodafile.getAbsoluteFile());
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
           publishProgress(""+ (int) ((total * 100) /lengthofdownfile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
```

Comment: Firstly,I need show the website with WebView control. It's not just downloading a web file.I need the  content length of webSite first page and relative images,css and other elements